# Can I delete a rails migration file if I have not done a db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a rails migration with

```
rails g migration CreateThisWeekView
```

I then realised it has the wrong name.  As I have not done a 'db:migrate' can I just delete it and re-create the one with the correct name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `rails generate` creates files, it doesn't do anything else. `rails generate migration` just creates a migration file, it doesn't change the database, so you can just delete the file.

You can delete the file manually or by using `rails destroy`:

```
rails d migration CreateThisWeekView
```

`destroy` is the command to undo code generated with `generate`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, try with the opposite to create a migration, that's destroying it, like:

```
$ rails d migration CreateThisWeekView
```

Without having modified the structure of your schema you don't need to make a rollback. I guess just destroying the created files you can achieve what you want.